# C# Permutations of String for n = ((n - 1) + (n - 2))

Tags: c#

I’m new to `C#` and I am trying to make a program that takes an input and figures out moves: 1 move or 2 moves and all the combinations (permutations) of these moves.

My formula is `n = ((n - 1) + (n - 2))`

The issue I am having is trying to output the results – I tried looping through them with if then else logic but it’s a mess. I’m not sure how to build an array to support the permutations.

```
If I move n=1 the result is 1 (1)
If I move n=2 the results is 2 (11,2)
If I move n=3 the results is  3 (111,12,21)
If I move n=4 the results is  4 (1111,112,211,121,22)
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleAppFrog
{
public class Program
{
    public void Main(string[] args)
    {

       // Number of moves by using only 1 or 2 moves

        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number of moves?");

        int myNumber = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        int combenations = 0;

        Console.WriteLine("You Chose " + myNumber + " moves :)");
        // Math = ((myNumber - 1) + (myNumber - 2)) = combenations 
        combenations = ((myNumber - 1) + (myNumber - 2));
        Console.WriteLine("There are " + combenations + " combinations of moves");

        // Need to output the permutations of combenations 
        var moves = "";

        // Gives the 1 moves            
        for (int i = 1; i <= myNumber; i++)
        {
            moves += "1 ";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(moves);

        var moves2 = "";

        // Get the 2 moves and check for remainder
        for (int i = 1; i <= (myNumber / 2); i++)
        {
            moves2 += "2 ";
        }

        var moves3 = "";

        //need to add on 1 move if there is a remainder
        if (myNumber % 2 != 0)
        {
            moves3 += "1 ";
        }

        Console.WriteLine(moves2 + moves3);
        Console.WriteLine(moves3 + moves2);
        // Stuck trying to figure out the rest of moves

        //-------------------------------------------------------------------------

        Console.WriteLine("Done...");
        Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `n = ((n - 1) + (n - 2))` doesn't make sense with your output. Given `n=1`, we have `1 = (1 - 1) + (1 - 2)`, or: `1 = 0 - 1`.

Comment: what you need actually?what is the code you have given?

Comment: Added my code above. Need a better way to output my moves.

Answer (score 1):

You'd probably have better luck with a recursive function.

**EDIT**
It looks like this in your code

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleAppFrog
{
    public class Program
    {
        public void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Number of moves by using only 1 or 2 moves

           Console.WriteLine("Enter a number of moves?");

           int myNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

           GenerateMoves (myNumber);

           Console.WriteLine("Done...");
           Console.Read();
       }

       static void GenerateMoves(int n) {
           GenerateMoves (n, "");
       }

       static void GenerateMoves(int n, string permutation) {
           if (n==0) { System.Console.WriteLine (permutation); }
           else {
               if (n>=1) { GenerateMoves (n-1, permutation + "1"); }
               if (n>=2) { GenerateMoves (n-2, permutation + "2"); }
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Normally I would suggest an answer closer to the OP's attempt / thought process, but this solution is so elegant and efficient and I wouldn't know how to solve this without recursion.

Comment: Thank you very much :) it does work well. I am trying to understand static void GenerateMoves - how does it work?

Comment: I don't know that I can effectively explain recursion in 600 characters. You will probably receive more benefit by stepping through the code in the debugger. Add "n" and "permutation" to the "Watch" window and observe each variable as they change. It may be helpful to draw what you observe on a piece of paper as a graph. Researching recursion and stack frames may be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks Joe. I did some research and watch a video and I have a better understanding now.